# Sharepoint 2010 - List View Threshold

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-list

I am doing POC in Sharepoint 2010. I give List View Threshold value as 2000 and Daily Time Window for Large Queries as 1.00 PM - 2.00 PM.I have folder which contains more than 6500 files.While i am trying to access that folder by 6.00 PM. it doesn't shows any error.Can any one say why the sharepoint doesn't shows any error?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solution :
  It works only for normal user.. if you are using site collection administrator or farm administrator LVT doesn't applied. eventhough you applying LVT value for administrator.

Thanks to João Pinho

Answer (score 3):

I guess that's because you are probably a Site Collection administrator.

According to this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx the throttling value for SC administrators is 20000 itens:

```
List view threshold for auditors and administrators
20,000
```

Try to log in with a simple Contributor user, and you will se a list throttling warning when entering that list.

Regards.

Comment: @MuraliG u're welcome, sorry to ask, but why didn't you marked it as answered?